# Isolate untrusted devices on home network

Tags: router, security, wireless-router, home-networking

How can I use a second router to help isolate my smart devices and improve my network security?

My smart devices need a WiFi password uploading to the manufacturer's servers to operate correctly. (Actually, they may not get uploaded to the server, but I cannot be sure they are not.)

Let's say

- Router 1 is connected to the internet
- Router 2 connects to Router 1 via Ethernet cable
- My phone, laptop, etc (trusted devices) connect to Router 1 wirelessly
- My smart devices (untrusted devices) are only given the wireless password to Router 2.

The idea would be to limit the damage which is done if the smart-device manufacturers leak details about my router (such as the WiFi password, or anything else they could leak).

I managed to set up Router 2 as its own DHCP server, and to get internet access working if I connect to Router 2. I set it up to use the range 192.168.2.*, so as to not conflict with the 192.168.1.* range of Router 1.

I was disappointed to find that when connected to Router 2, I could still navigate to 192.168.1.1 and access the admin page of Router 1.

Some direct sub-questions:

- Is there any advantage to trying to do this?
- How do I stop anything connected to Router 2 from accessing anything in the 192.168.1.* range?
- What else should I do to improve my security?
- Can I expect to retain full functionality of smart devices?

Comment: I would question the assumption that a smart device would leak router details any more than a computer. I have Cisco VPN router as Main and a Cisco Wireless router attached to it on the same subnet. The router admin pages (both) have been secured with a very strong password and remote management has been turned off. Wireless access is via a particularly long and highly secure password. It has been like this for some years and no one has accessed it (but me) and secured devices do not leak out details

Comment: *How do I stop anything connected to Router 2 from accessing anything in the 192.168.1.* range?* Use according router2's firewall deny rules.